# ft2build.h: No such file or directory на Linux Fedora

Tags: linux, cmake, fedora

Пытаюсь скомпилировать приложение через Cmake на Федора Линукс и получаю такую ошибку

```
fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
   35 | #include <ft2build.h>
```

Стоит отметить то, что freetype-devel в систему уже установлен

Comment: `dnf provides '*/ft2build.h'` does seem to show it in `freetype-devel`.  Maybe [`FindFreetype`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindFreetype.html) `cmake-module` will help?